# Is it possible to view documents created under a certain hierarchy

Tags: google-drive

Is it possible to view documents created under a certain hierarchy.

e.g.

Company admin UserA creates FolderA/SubFolderA/DocumentA.pdf
Company admin UserA creates FolderB/SubFolderB/DocumentB.pdf

But if the above documents are shared to company users UserB & UserC, they don't see the same hierarchy when they view Google docs under Google Drive (http://drive.google.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to share the entire folder with them (top level folder). Otherwise the docs themselves are shared, rather than the folder structure. The added benefit here is that now, anytime a new file is added to the folder structure, it will be shared with the other people in the shared folder as well.

Take note: once you share the folder structure with others, then any shared recipients can make changes (e.g. delete) folders from the structure.